# Need Help building a login system for my website

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, login-script

Im building a login system in html with form. Heres The HTML and css.

Would php work?

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="ie6 ielt8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie7 ielt8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Paper Stack</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="loginstyle.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
 <section id="content">
  <form action="">
   <h1>Login Form</h1>
   <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" required="" id="username" />
   </div>
   <div>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required="" id="password" />
   </div>
   <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
    <a href="#">Lost your password?</a>
    <a href="#">Register</a>
   </div>
  </form><!-- form -->
  <div class="button">
   <a href="#">Download source file</a>
  </div><!-- button -->
 </section><!-- content -->
</div><!-- container -->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```css
/* Reset CSS */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 outline: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 vertical-align: baseline;
 background: transparent;
}
body {
 background: #DCDDDF url(http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/7/7AF2Qzt.png);
 color: #000;
 font: 14px Arial;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 position: relative;
}
h1{ font-size:28px;}
h2{ font-size:26px;}
h3{ font-size:18px;}
h4{ font-size:16px;}
h5{ font-size:14px;}
h6{ font-size:12px;}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{ color:#563D64;}
small{ font-size:10px;}
b, strong{ font-weight:bold;}
a{ text-decoration: none; }
a:hover{ text-decoration: underline; }
.left { float:left; }
.right { float:right; }
.alignleft { float: left; margin-right: 15px; }
.alignright { float: right; margin-left: 15px; }
.clearfix:after,
form:after {
 content: ".";
 display: block;
 height: 0;
 clear: both;
 visibility: hidden;
}
.container { margin: 25px auto; position: relative; width: 900px; }
#content {
 background: #f9f9f9;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(248,248,248,1) 0%, rgba(249,249,249,1) 100%);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(248,248,248,1) 0%,rgba(249,249,249,1) 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(248,248,248,1) 0%,rgba(249,249,249,1) 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(248,248,248,1) 0%,rgba(249,249,249,1) 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(248,248,248,1) 0%,rgba(249,249,249,1) 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f8f8f8', endColorstr='#f9f9f9',GradientType=0 );
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff inset;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff inset;
 -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff inset;
 -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff inset;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff inset;
 border: 1px solid #c4c6ca;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 25px 0 0;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
 width: 400px;
}
#content h1 {
 color: #7E7E7E;
 font: bold 25px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 letter-spacing: -0.05em;
 line-height: 20px;
 margin: 10px 0 30px;
}
#content h1:before,
#content h1:after {
 content: "";
 height: 1px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 width: 27%;
}
#content h1:after {
 background: rgb(126,126,126);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(126,126,126,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(126,126,126,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(126,126,126,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(126,126,126,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(left,  rgba(126,126,126,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
    right: 0;
}
#content h1:before {
 background: rgb(126,126,126);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(right,  rgba(126,126,126,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right,  rgba(126,126,126,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(right,  rgba(126,126,126,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(right,  rgba(126,126,126,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(right,  rgba(126,126,126,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
    left: 0;
}
#content:after,
#content:before {
 background: #f9f9f9;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(248,248,248,1) 0%, rgba(249,249,249,1) 100%);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(248,248,248,1) 0%,rgba(249,249,249,1) 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(248,248,248,1) 0%,rgba(249,249,249,1) 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(248,248,248,1) 0%,rgba(249,249,249,1) 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(248,248,248,1) 0%,rgba(249,249,249,1) 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f8f8f8', endColorstr='#f9f9f9',GradientType=0 );
 border: 1px solid #c4c6ca;
 content: "";
 display: block;
 height: 100%;
 left: -1px;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
}
#content:after {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(2deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(2deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(2deg);
 transform: rotate(2deg);
 top: 0;
 z-index: -1;
}
#content:before {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
 transform: rotate(-3deg);
 top: 0;
 z-index: -2;
}
#content form { margin: 0 20px; position: relative }
#content form input[type="text"],
#content form input[type="password"] {
 -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
 -moz-border-radius: 3px;
 -ms-border-radius: 3px;
 -o-border-radius: 3px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 0 -2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.08) inset;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 0 -2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.08) inset;
 -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 0 -2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.08) inset;
 -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 0 -2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.08) inset;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 0 -2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.08) inset;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 transition: all 0.5s ease;
 background: #eae7e7 url(http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/8/8bcLQqF.png) no-repeat;
 border: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
 color: #777;
 font: 13px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 margin: 0 0 10px;
 padding: 15px 10px 15px 40px;
 width: 80%;
}
#content form input[type="text"]:focus,
#content form input[type="password"]:focus {
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #ed1c24 inset;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #ed1c24 inset;
 -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #ed1c24 inset;
 -o-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #ed1c24 inset;
 box-shadow: 0 0 2px #ed1c24 inset;
 background-color: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #ed1c24;
 outline: none;
}
#username { background-position: 10px 10px !important }
#password { background-position: 10px -53px !important }
#content form input[type="submit"] {
 background: rgb(254,231,154);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,231,154,1) 0%, rgba(254,193,81,1) 100%);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,231,154,1) 0%,rgba(254,193,81,1) 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,231,154,1) 0%,rgba(254,193,81,1) 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,231,154,1) 0%,rgba(254,193,81,1) 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,231,154,1) 0%,rgba(254,193,81,1) 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fee79a', endColorstr='#fec151',GradientType=0 );
 -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
 -moz-border-radius: 30px;
 -ms-border-radius: 30px;
 -o-border-radius: 30px;
 border-radius: 30px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.8) inset;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.8) inset;
 -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.8) inset;
 -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.8) inset;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.8) inset;
 border: 1px solid #D69E31;
 color: #85592e;
 cursor: pointer;
 float: left;
 font: bold 15px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 height: 35px;
 margin: 20px 0 35px 15px;
 position: relative;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
 width: 120px;
}
#content form input[type="submit"]:hover {
 background: rgb(254,193,81);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,193,81,1) 0%, rgba(254,231,154,1) 100%);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,193,81,1) 0%,rgba(254,231,154,1) 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,193,81,1) 0%,rgba(254,231,154,1) 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,193,81,1) 0%,rgba(254,231,154,1) 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,193,81,1) 0%,rgba(254,231,154,1) 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fec151', endColorstr='#fee79a',GradientType=0 );
}
#content form div a {
 color: #004a80;
    float: right;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 30px 15px 0 0;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.button {
 background: rgb(247,249,250);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(247,249,250,1) 0%, rgba(240,240,240,1) 100%);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(247,249,250,1) 0%,rgba(240,240,240,1) 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(247,249,250,1) 0%,rgba(240,240,240,1) 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(247,249,250,1) 0%,rgba(240,240,240,1) 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(247,249,250,1) 0%,rgba(240,240,240,1) 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f7f9fa', endColorstr='#f0f0f0',GradientType=0 );
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1) inset;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1) inset;
 -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1) inset;
 -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1) inset;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1) inset;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
 -o-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
 -ms-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
 border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
 border-top: 1px solid #CFD5D9;
 padding: 15px 0;
}
.button a {
 background: url(http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/8/8bcLQqF.png) 0 -112px no-repeat;
 color: #7E7E7E;
 font-size: 17px;
 padding: 2px 0 2px 40px;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.button a:hover {
 background-position: 0 -135px;
 color: #00aeef;
}
```

When the user enter submit i would like it to check a txt file with usernames and passwords. The text file is formatted like this:

```html
username1:password1
username2:password2
username3:password3
```

I want to grab the first line, split it to "username1" and "password1", and then post to this:

```html
br.form['login'] = 'username1'
br.form['passwd'] = 'password1'
```

EDIT
I know this php code will write the username and password to a txt file. I just need help doing the opposite.

PHP (Register)

```html
<?php

//If Submit Button Is Clicked Do the Following
if ($_POST['Login']){

$myFile = "log.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $_POST['username'] . ":";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = $_POST['password'] . "\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);

} ?>
```

After that, I want it to repeat and move onto username2:password2.

I saw this exact post for python but i would like to do this in html, Php ,Or JavaScrypt any help

Comment: This is not possible to do with html. You need a server side language

Comment: how about javascrypt or php?

Comment: javascript is no server side language... but php is.
Just enter 'how to make login php' at google and you'll find what you're looking for ;)

Comment: "i would like it to check a txt file with usernames and passwords"  I think you need to do a little more research about all this before you get too much further into this project.

Answer (score 0):

PHP would be a good option. First familiarise yourself with the language then look in to the functions related to files e.g. fwrite() and fread().

**Edit:**

Look in to fgets(). That way you can put the username and password posted from the form and compare it against the file line by line.

Comment: Then read up on it. This may sound harsh but YOU need to learn to learn. Then when you're stuck ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP.

Also it is never a good idea to store passwords in plain text. You should do some hashing of passwords and then store them. You can use PHP's password hashing API. You can read more about [PHP's password hashing API](https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-5-5-password-hashing-api/)

Also, I am not sure why you are storing password in plain text, you probably can use database (like MySQL) to store the details.

However, if you want only a layer of password protection before the users can access your site then you can use .htaccess and .htpasswd to add a layer of authentication on your site.  When you add this, the users will have to enter a password before they can access the site. You can read more about about [Authentication using .htaccess file](https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/htaccess-tips/#htaccess_authentication)

If you don't need database and don't want to use the .htaccess method and want to use file, then you might want to read on [fgets()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) and [fread()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php). Also, if you are using the file to store passwords, then don't have it accessible from the website (i.e. using some URL in browser). Store the file is some location which cannot be reached by some URL on your site. This will prevent others to download your password file.

Comment: I will do that further down the road. I just want to understand how to read from the file. I know how to write to it but not read.

Comment: If you want to just add a password before the users can access your site you can use .htaccess. I just updated the answer to add more details about it.